# How to specify file type while saving the file by using "save as" menu item in netbeans

Tags: netbeans

How to specify file type while saving the file by using "save as" menu item in netbeans. I can see only "all files" for saving the files in an drive. But i need to include the file extension, while saving the file in the drive.

Comment: Have you tried it and seen what it does? Worse case you manually change the names afterwords.

Comment: I don't know why this question was migrated here. It belongs on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), as it is a specific question about computer software.